# Maintaining source code and testing code in a single git repository

Tags: git, makefile

I'm developing a "generic" make setup to use when working on my projects. The setup consists of a master Makefile and a file 'module.mk' that is supposed to reside in subdirs relative to master Makefile. The master Makfile include-s several module.mk's from specified directories. I started developing this using git for version control.

Parallel to developing Makefile and module.mk I would like to develop a test case for testing and illustrative purposes. Ideally the test case would have a structure like this:

```
./Makefile
./dir1/module.mk
./dir2/module.mk
```

plus some additional files inside dir1 and dir2

The files dir1/module.mk and dir2/module.mk might include some specific modifications as compared to the "source code" version. They will also be a bit different from each other.

My question is:

What would be the optimal git workflow to maintain both the development of the make setup (Makefile and module.mk) and the test case code?

Can it be done using a single git repo (with branches perhaps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended-up using branches, like both @Dherik and @spuder suggested. To resolve the problem of testing code residing in a separate directory of the git repo I create files Makefile and module.mk in the testing supdir that mostly `include` the source code.

In particular, the repo looks like

```
./Makefile
./module.mk
test/Makefile
test/dir1/module.mk
test/dir2/module.mk
```

with directory `test` present only on "testing" branch and files `Makefile` and `module.mk`'s within "test" mostly include `Makefile` and `module.mk` from repository root.

Thanks for inputs!

Answer (score 1):

I think branch is the answer, if I undertood correct. Why?

If the "specific modifications" are few, I understand that could be a lot of code in common between "source code" version and "test" version. In this case, you will need sometimes to correct/update the same code in both versions, and will be useful a "hotfix" branch that you will merge in the "source code" and "test" branch.

**Update**

1 - Create a testing_code branch from master (where you already have this files), like:

```
git branch -b testing_code master
```

2 - When you need to do some correction in the common code, you can create a "hotfix_whatever" branch, from testing_code or master, like:

```
git branch -b hotfix_whatever master
```

3 - Do the correction in hotfix_whatever and merge in master and testing_code.

Merge in testing_code:

```
git checkout testing_code
git merge hotfix_whatever
```

and merge in master:

```
git checkout master
git merge hotfix_whatever
```

4 - Delete the branch after merge:

```
git branch -d hotfix_whatever
```

With this kind of work cycle, you can mantain the 2 branchs syncronized and updated without problems. Every time that you need do a correction, open a new branch, do the modifications, and merge in master and testing_code.

Comment: thanks, but can you provide some more details about your solution? If I keep Makefile and module.mk in master branch, how should I create the branch for the testing code and how to use the 'hotfix' branch you mentioned?

Comment: thanks. That part I understood. What I still don't know how to do is the layout of the repo. At this moment I have Makefile and module.mk in the root dir of the repo. The testing code requires at least that there are at least two copies of module.mk in separate directories that are customized a little bit for testing. What I would like ideally, is that if I make some generic change to source of module.mk, it could be easily "merged" with the customized copies in the subdirs.

Comment: One possibility is create a patch from module.mk to apply in the customized copies every time you make a change.

If you change the original module.mk, you can do a diff and store the difference in a file, to apply as a patch in customizes copies: `git diff module.mk >> modified_module.patch`. What I cannot answer is how you could do that in a automatic way, because are different files in different folders. But, with the patch, you can apply manually.

Answer (score 0):

Git branches are very inexpensive.

Create a development branch for every permutation of module 1 and 2.  You can merge branches easily down the road if necessary.

Consider this project which uses many different branches.

https://github.com/adaptivecomputing/torque

Comment: Thanks a lot. See my comment to Dherik answer above. Can you provide some more details about your solution too?